# Xcode Behaviors Preferences

Tags: xcode4

I am not able to see the +/- on the left pane (Events pane) of my Xcode 4 Behaviors Preferences as shown in the link below.  Any idea why?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-alerts_preferences/Recipe.html

Comment: Are you running Xcode 4.0? Xcode 4.1 added the ability to add custom behaviors.

Comment: Yes Xcode 4.0, thanks, that explains it.  Can you answer it? I will pick your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason why is that you're running Xcode 4.0. Xcode 4.1 added the ability to add custom behaviors. If you're running Xcode 4.0, there are no plus-minus buttons.